# File reading and regex - Python

Tags: python, regex, string, file

I read a file which has a line : `Fixes: Saurabh Likes python`

I want to remove the `Fixes:` part of above line. I am employing regex for that
but the snippet below returns output like

```
Saurabh Likes python\r
```

I am wondering where `\r` is coming from. I tried all strip options for removing it like `rstrip()`, `lstrip()`, etc. But nothing worked. Could anybody suggest me the way to get rid of `\r`.

```
patternFixes ='\s*'+'Fixes'+':'+'\s*'
matchFixes= re.search(patternFixes,line, re.IGNORECASE)
        if matchFixes:
                    patternCompiled = re.compile(patternFixes)
                    line=patternCompiled.sub("", line)
                    #line=line.lstrip()
                    relevantInfo = relevantInfo+line
                    continue
```

Thanks in advance!
-Saurabh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestion to get rid of `\r`:

I suppose you have opened your file using `open(filename)`. Following the [manual](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#open) of open:

> If mode is omitted, it defaults to 'r'. ... In addition to the
>   standard fopen() values mode may be 'U' or 'rU'. Python is usually
>   built with universal newlines support; supplying 'U' opens the file as
>   a text file, but lines may be terminated by any of the following: the
>   Unix end-of-line convention '\n', the Macintosh convention '\r', or
>   the Windows convention '\r\n'. All of these external representations
>   are seen as '\n' by the Python program.

So, in short, please try to open your file using `'rU'` and see if the `\r` vanishes:

```
with open(filename, "rU") as f:
    # do your stuff here.
    ...
```

Does the `\r` vanish in your output?

Of course your code looks rather clunky, but other have already commented on this part.

Answer (score 0):

You probably opened the file in binary mode (`open(filename, "rb")` or something like that). Don't do this if you're working with text files.

Use `open(filename)` instead. Now Python will automatically normalize all newlines to `\n`, regardless of the current platform.

Also, why not simply `patternFixes = r'\s*Fixes:\s*'`? Why all the `+`es?

Then, you're doing a lot of unnecessary stuff like recompiling a regex over and over.

So, my suggestion (which does the same thing as your code (plus the file handling):

```
r = re.compile(r'\s*Fixes:\s*')
with open(filename) as infile:
    relevantInfo = "".join(r.sub("", line) for line in infile if "Fixes:" in line)
```

Comment: I did not open file in binary mode

Comment: I removed the +es but I see the same output

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub('Fixes:\s*', '', 'Fixes: Saurabh Likes python')
'Saurabh Likes python'
```

No '\r'

```
>>> re.sub('\s*'+'Fixes'+':'+'\s*', '', 'Fixes: Saurabh Likes python')
'Saurabh Likes python'
```

No '\r' again

can you provide more details on how to reproduce?

**EDIt** cannot reproduce with your code neither

```
>>> line = 'Fixes: Saurabh Likes python'
>>> patternFixes ='\s*'+'Fixes'+':'+'\s*'
>>> matchFixes= re.search(patternFixes,line, re.IGNORECASE)
>>> if matchFixes:
...     patternCompiled = re.compile(patternFixes)
...     line=patternCompiled.sub("", line)
...     print line
...     line=line.lstrip()
...     print line
... 
Saurabh Likes python
Saurabh Likes python
>>>
```

Comment: That's because the problem occurs before the code he posted. See my answer.

Comment: Yeah, that well may be the case. I'm trying to encourage OP to post more code and details.

Answer (score 0):

The '\r' is a carriage return -- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carriage_return, and it's being picked up from your file.

I will note that if all the lines you need to 'fix' actually DO start with "Fixes: " and that's all you want to change, you could just do something like:

```
line = line[line.find('Fixes: ')+7:-1]
```

Saves you all the regex stuff. Not sure on performance, though. And this SHOULD kill your '\r's at the same time.

Comment: Employing your way gave me output like Saurabh Likes python\       '\r' did not got completely.. rather only r went

Comment: Ah - well, if it's reading '\r' as two characters, then ending at the second to last character would achieve the desired outcome.